# Toggle visibility of 2 divs with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with my code

I am trying to show 1 div (**show_1**) by default and then hide it and show a second div (**show_2**) when button 2 is clicked. And then when button 1 is clicked hide **show_2** and show **show_1** again

https://jsfiddle.net/mgzurjgL/4/

It is not working though, nothing happens when I click either buttons.

```js
function switch_div(show_1, show_2) {
  var a = document.getElementById(show_1);
  var a2 = document.getElementById(show_2);
  if (a.style.display == 'block') {
    a.style.display = 'block';
    a2.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a2.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2');">
  1
</div>
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2');">
  2
</div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>
<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Show this div when button 2 is clicked
</div>
```

Comment: surely its because you pass the same values to switch_div both times ?

Comment: I thought so too until I tried switching it, for some reason JSFiddle is not recognizing `switch_div` as a function and thats odd.

Comment: The settings were wrong in JSFiddle that's why `switch_div` was not being recognized. the script was being ran in a wrapped `onload` function and not in the head (not globally).

Comment: You need to understand how to use JSFiddle because I think that was more of the error than your code.

Comment: In JSfiddle you need to change the Javascript options from "on load" to "no wrap in <head>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had your settings wrong in JSFiddle, you need to run the script in the head not onload. Also you passed in the same parameters twice. Also why dont you try something simpler like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/mgzurjgL/5/

```js
function switch_div(show) {  
  document.getElementById("show_"+show).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("show_"+((show==1)?2:1)).style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div(1);">
  1
</div>
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div(2);">
  2
</div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>
<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Show this div when button 2 is clicked
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two items: script placement and a typo.  Working version at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lwnfqjg/1/), tested in Google Chrome.

1. The script has to run before the `divs`.  In the JSFiddle Javascript settings, I changed "Load Type" to "No wrap - in `<head>`."  This way the `switch_div` function exists when the `div`s are loaded.
2. There was a typo:

   ```
   if (a.style.display == 'block')
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if (a.style.display == 'none')
   ```

   Otherwise you are setting `block` display on an element that's already `block` :) .

**Edit**: This code still doesn't do what you appear to want, because the function you have written toggles the `div` visibility regardless of which button is pressed.  What you really want is in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lwnfqjg/2/):

```
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2', true);">
```

and

```
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2', false);">
```

together with

```
function switch_div(show_1, show_2, should_show_1) {  
   var a = document.getElementById(show_1);
   var a2 = document.getElementById(show_2);
   if(should_show_1) {
      a.style.display = 'block';             
      a2.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
      a.style.display = 'none';            
      a2.style.display = 'block';
   }              
}
```

That way you get only the `div` you want.

Comment: Solved my problem and also helped further realising what I was trying to achieve, thank you. I chose a different answer simply because it was shorter js, although I know yours was longer only because you kept it based on my js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the statements in if-else or change the condition in the if to "if (a.style.display !== 'block') "

When a.style.display is 'block' then you have to set it to 'none' to hide it.

```js
function switch_div(show_1, show_2) {
  var a = document.getElementById(show_1);
  var a2 = document.getElementById(show_2);
  if (a.style.display !== 'block') {
    a.style.display = 'block';
    a2.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a2.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2');">
  1
</div>
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2');">
  2
</div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>
<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Show this div when button 2 is clicked
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the js function and the "call" for buttons.

```js
function switch_div(show_1, show_2) {  
var a = document.getElementById(show_2);
var a2 = document.getElementById(show_1);
a.style.display = 'none';            
a2.style.display = 'block';            
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_1', 'show_2');">
  1
</div>
<div class="button" onclick="switch_div('show_2', 'show_1');">
  2
</div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>
<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Show this div when button 2 is clicked
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works with:

```
    <div class="button" onclick="switch_div(1,2);">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="button" onclick="switch_div(2,1);">
    2
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="show_1">
    Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
    </div>
    <div class="content hide" id="show_2">
    Show this div when button 2 is clicked
    </div>


    <script>
    function switch_div(n1,n2) {  
        document.getElementById("show_"+n1).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("show_"+n2).style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
```